# Proof verification: prove $A\cup (B\cap C) = (A\cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Can someone please verify whether my proof is logically correct? :)

Proof: Let $x\in A \cup (B\cap C)$. Then $x\in A$ or $x\in B\cap C$. If $x\in A$, then $x \in A\cup B$ and $x\in A\cup C$ (since for any sets A and B, $A\subseteq A\cup B$). If $x\in B\cap C$, then $x\in B$ and $x\in C$. Then $x\in A\cup B$ and $x\in A\cup C$. In either case, $x\in (A\cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$. Then $A \cup (B\cap C) \subset (A\cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$.

Let $x\in (A\cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$. Then $x\in A\cup B$ and $x\in A\cup C$. Then $x\in A$ or $x\in B\cap C$. Then $x\in A \cup (B\cap C)$. Then $(A\cup B) \cap (A \cup C) \subset A \cup (B\cap C)$. Therefore, $A\cup (B\cap C) = (A\cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$. $\square$

Comment: Your proof is correct, well done!

Comment: The first containment looks good.  For the second containment, I feel like there is a little gap:  why do you automatically know that either $x \in A$ or $x\in B\cap C$?  You aren't *wrong*, it just seems like you skipped a step.

Comment: well, if $x$ is not in $A$ then it should be in $B$ and $C$ since it is in the intersection

Comment: But there's a step missing when going from $x\in{A}\cap{B}\land{x}\in{A}\cap{C}$ to $x\in{A}\lor{x}\in{B}\cap{C}$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I agree, when I wrote the second part, I did not use this wording, I wrote something longer (Then $x\in A$ or $x\in B$ and $x\in A$ or $x\in C$. If $x\in A$, then $x \in A \cup (B\cap C)$. If $x\in B$ and $x\in C$, then $x\in B \cap C$. Then $x\in A \cup (B\cap C)$. Therefore...). However, the textbook answer key to this question used what I wrote in the original question, so I wanted to see whether people found this too short and not clear! What do you think of my longer version in parentheses?

Comment: I am more comfortable with your shorter proof.

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani Okay! Thanks! Are you sure it's not too short and missing important steps?

Comment: Looks good to me. Have you done the audits?

Comment: Sorry, what is an audits?

Comment: @numericalorange As I said, your original proof is not wrong, there is just a very small gap that, if I were your instructor, I would want to see filled.  I probably would have added a sentence to the effect of "As $x \in (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$, either $x \in A$, or $x\not\in A$ in which case $x\in B$ and $x\in C$."  But, as I said, it is a minor hole, and any appropriately mature student or mathematician would not be unduly troubled by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is flawless. You have used some proper subset notation when you meant to use the subset notation. You also missed to close a parenthesis. With a little editing the proof will be an excellent one.

Comment: I don't think it matters whether $\subseteq$ or $\subset$ is used when proving set containment, because in some textbooks $\subset$ is equivalent to $\subseteq$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I agree with your statement about different textbooks.Personally I like $ \subset$ for proper subset.

Comment: @numericalorange yes, in my textbook it is. I was always wondering what a *proper* subset was because it was never mentioned in the book... but I can see clearly now (the rain is gone).

Comment: I use $\subset$ for proper subset and think of the proof of set containment as "if x > y and x < y, then x = y" sort of thinking. I never use $\subset$ for non-proper subsets, it really irks me!!